# Redirect to homepage when empty

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have my pages working, but when I have a situation like below:

```
www.mysite.com
www.misite.com/
www.miste.com/index.php
```

I need it to redirect to www.mysite.com/home/ (and show this to the user).

Can I do that using .htaccess?

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?par=$1

ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've not have typos in your question:

```
www.mysite.com
www.misite.com/
www.miste.com/index.php
```

And all three domains point to the same document root. You want something like this:

```
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(mysite|misite|miste)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ http://www.mysite.com/home/ [L,R=301]
```